CiviEvent: "Confirmation" and "Thank You" screen displayed in website backend after upgrading to 5.72.0
I'm currently using CiviCRM version 5.72.0 with WordPress 6.5.
I've encountered an odd issue after upgrading from 5.71.2 to 5.72.0. When individuals attempt to register for an event, the initial page of the event registration screen appears correctly on the frontend of the website. However, both the "confirmation" and "thank you for registration" screens are now appearing from the website backend, which is not typical. As these screens are located in the website backend, WordPress prompts users to log in, resulting in many individuals being unable to register for our events since they are not members. Is anyone else experiencing this issue after upgrading to 5.72.0?
Update
I deleted the 5.72.0 codebase and replaced it 5.71.2 version, and now  both the "confirmation" and "thank you for registration" screens appear on the website frontend, allowing people to register for our events again.
However, the CiviCRM system status now displays an "unexpected database version" error due to a mismatch between the database and files.

Yes it's a bug. See https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/5127#note_162796

@aaron a patch has been released: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-wordpress/pull/318.  If you know how to apply patches, you can upgrade to 5.72 with this.  Otherwise, 5.72.1 should be released pretty soon (this is a serious bug, I think it alone justifies releasing 5.72.1) and you can upgrade then.

Thanks for working on it over the weekend.  I reinstalled version 5.72.0 and applied the patch.  This is to confirm that I'm not experiencing the issue again.
